# Генератор случайных чисел без повторений С++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, случайные-числа, генераторы

Такая беда. Код работает почти без нареканий, но есть одно "но". Постоянно повторяется элемент массива array[0] с каким-либо другим элементом. Есть подозрение, что беда внутри второго цикла, который производит проверку значений по массиву, но не вижу, где косяк. Помогите, люди добрые.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <random>

int main ()
{
    int n;
    int array[100]={0};

    for(int i=0;i<=31;i++)
    {
        n=rand()%32;
        for(int j=0;j<=31;j++)
        {
            if(n==array[j]) 
            {
                j=0;
                n=rand()%32;
            }       
        }
        array[i]=n;
        printf("%d\n",n);   
    }
}
```

Дополняемся. Поппробовал воспользоваться советом @Harry. Выходит странная последовательность нулей на выходе.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <random>

int main ()
{
    int array[100]={0};
    int j, n, k;
    for(int i=1;i<=32;i++)
    {
        array[i]=i;
        printf("%d ",i);
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(int i=1;i<=32;i++)
    {
        n=rand()%32+i;

        j=array[i];
        k=array[n];
        array[i]=k;
        array[n]=j;

        printf("%d ",array[i]);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы хотите распределить 32 последовательных числа (0..31) случайным образом? Запишите их и перемешайте, поочередно обменивая каждый элемент i со случайно выбранным из диапазона [i..31] - это гарантирует равномерное случайное перемешивание. Быстрее  будет...

Comment: вы seed не устанавливайте в генератор случайных чисел, а вообще лучше сделать массив в нужном диапазоне и сделать шаффл(std::shuffle) тогда повторений случайных чисел также не будет и асимптотика улучшится

Comment: @Ildar `seed` тут ни при чем, у него сам алгоритм проверки корявый...

Comment: Заполните массив числами по-порядку и перемешайте с помощью алгоритма `std::shuffle`.

Comment: По совету  @Harry нужно так : `for(int i=0;i<32;i++)
    {
        n=rand()%(32-i)+i;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По ходу выполнения работы оказалось, что нужен рандомайзер для двухмерного массива, но это уже не оказалось такой проблемой, поскольку выше дали ответ. Слегка переделал код, но пускай тоже здесь повисит, мало ли, кому-нибудь да пригодится.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <random>

int main ()
{
    using namespace std;

    int i,j,num=0;
    int a[8][8]={0};

    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<8;j++)
        {
            num++;
            a[i][j]=num;
        }

    }

    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<8;j++)
        {
            int btwi=rand()%(8-i)+i;
            int btwj=rand()%(8-j)+j;
            int t=a[i][j]; a[i][j]=a[btwi][btwj]; a[btwi][btwj]=t;
        }   
    }

    for(int i=0;i<8;++i) 
    for(int j=0;j<8;++j) 
    cout << a[i][j] << " ";

    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот мое предложение:

```
int main()
{
    int a[32];
    for(int i = 0; i < 32; ++i) a[i] = i;

    for(int i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
    {
        int j = rand()%(32-i)+i;
        int t = a[i]; a[i] = a[j]; a[j] = t;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 32; ++i) cout << a[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

}
```

Или, используя стандартную библиотеку,

```
int a[32];
for(int i = 0; i < 32; ++i) a[i] = i;

shuffle(a,a+32,default_random_engine(random_device()()));

for(int i = 0; i < 32; ++i) cout << a[i] << " ";
cout << endl;
```

Ваш способ должен выглядеть так:

```
for(int n, i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
{
    bool ok;
    do {
        ok = true;
        n = rand()%32;
        for(int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
            if (a[j] == n) { ok = false; break; }
    } while(!ok);
    a[i] = n;
}
```

Только вот эксперимент показывает, что в моем случае всегда `rand()` вызывается 32 раза, в то время как в вашем - 130±39 раз (по 100000 экспериментов; минимально потребовалось 52 вызова, максимально - 416...)

Comment: В угоду миниатюрности и аккуратности очень пришелся по душе первый вариант. Благодарю.

Comment: Комментарий для тех, кто хочет реализовать на другом языке: Для генерации N не повторяющихся случайных чисел нужно 1) заполнить массив возрастающей последовательностью 2) перемешать массив

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Только перемешивать надо правильно - см. мой комментарий к вопросу... *перемешайте, поочередно обменивая каждый элемент i со случайно выбранным из диапазона [i..31] - это гарантирует равномерное случайное перемешивание*

Comment: Последнюю итерацию цикла можно исключить, т.к. элемент всегда будет меняться местами с самим собой

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    srand(time(NULL));

    int sizeOfArray;
    std::cout << "Введите размер массива: ";
    std::cin >> sizeOfArray;

    int* array = new int[sizeOfArray];

    bool already;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray;)
    {
        already = false;
        int valueForRand = rand() % 20;

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (array[i] == valueForRand)
            {
                already = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!already)
        {
            array[i] = valueForRand;
            i++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++)
    {
        std::cout << array[i] << "  ";
    }

    delete[] array;

    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

У вас неправильная проверка. Вот вам рабочий код.

Answer (score -1):

Для корректной работы рандома необходимо выставить srand() вначале. Рекомендую дописать srand(time(NULL));

Только не забудьте подключить библиотеку "ctime"